# FileObserver instance is being garbage collected

Tags: android, multithreading, fileobserver

I need to monitor all files in a folder, when a file opened (FileObserver.OPEN) I want to execute a method. The problem is some times, the FileObserver instance is collected by GC, I tried this:

```
    final MyFileObserver fo = new MyFileObserver("/mnt/sdcard/Musicas");
    threadFileObserver = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fo.startWatching();
        }
    };
    t = new Thread(threadFileObserver);
    t.run();
```

But is being collected.
The question is, what is the best solution for a instance of FileObserver not be collected?

tks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the startWatching() method returns immediately, your Thread finishes running, and your method returns. At this point, your FileObserver, being a local variable, is not visible from anywhere. Your thread has finished running and there is no reference to it. Both are garbage collected. Define the FileObserver as a static variable or a field in something that isn't garbage collected, not as a local variable in a method.

Comment: Where did you declare the static?

Comment: Also, are you trying to keep track of what happens to the file even if your app UI is not showing? What is the motivation behind what you are trying to do?

Comment: In main Activity. I think I need to keep the the Activity running in a background process or something like.

Comment: Did you exit the Activity in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, sometimes the user execute other application acessing by the main Android menu. I think this moment my instance is being collected. I tryied create a service and start the FileObserver instance, but not work.

Comment: OhHiThere, your answers helped me to find a path to the possible solution. tks man!!!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Did you put it in a service?

Comment: Yes, I created a service running in a background process, the listener of FileObserver is started after the service start up. With this solution the FileObserver not collected anymore. Tks for your help!!!

Comment: Could you post the solution?  That would really help others including me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Keep `fo` in the application scope by making it a global variable of your main/UI Activity.